# What is the best way to represent a tree in this case?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

I am trying to solve this question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/journey-to-the-moon I.e. a problem of finding connected components of a graph. What I have is a list of vertices (from 0 to N-1) and each line in the standard input gives me pair of vertices that are connected by an edge (i.e. if I have `1, 3`) it means that vertex 1 and vertex 3 are in one connected component. My question is what is the best way to store the inpit, i.e. how to represent my graph? My idea is to use ArrayList of Arraylist - each position in the array list stores another arraylist of adgecent vertices. This is the code:

```
 public static List<ArrayList<Integer>> graph;
```

and then in the `main()` method:

```
graph = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(N);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        graph.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
  //then for each line in the standard input I fill the corresponding values in the array:
   for (int j = 0; j < I; j++) {
        String[] line2 = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(line2[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(line2[1]);
        graph.get(a-1).add(b);
        graph.get(b-1).add(a);
    }
```

I'm pretti sure that for solving the question I have to put vertex `a` at position `b-1` and then vertex `b` at position `a-1` so this should not change. But what I am looking for is better way to represent the graph?

Comment: Note that you may have up to 100.000 vertices.  This may fit in memory in a simple array of arrays of longs.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this graph later? There are several graph representations, and they may depend on usage. There are solutions (taken from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)):

What you proposed is an Adjacency list which is basically a good option.

Comment: What you are doing is called 'adjacency list'. Maybe you could use List<LinkedList<Integer>>, as the number of adjacent vertices is unkown.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java's collections (ArrayList, for example) adds a lot of memory overhead. each Integer object will take at least 12 bytes, in addition to the 4 bytes required for storing the int.

Just use a huge single int array (let's call it  edgeArray), which represents the adjacency matrix. Enter 1 when the cell corresponds to an edge. e.g., if nodes k and m is seen on the input, then cell (k, m) will have 1, else 0. In the row major order, it will be the index k * N + m. i.e, edgeArray[k * N + m ] = 1. You can either choose [column major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order), or row major order. But then your int array will be very sparse. It's trivial to implement a sparse array. Just have an array for the non-zero indices in sorted order. It should be in sorted order so that you can binary search. The number of elements will be in the order of number of edges.

Of course, when you are building the adjacency matrix, you won't know how many edges are there. So you won't be able to allocate the array. Just use a hash set. Don't use HashSet, which is very inefficient. Look at IntOpenHashSet from fastutils. If you are not allowed to use libraries, implement one that is similar to that.

Let us say that the openHashMap variable you will be using is called adjacencyMatrix. So if you see, 3 and 2 and there are 10^6 nodes in total (N = 10^6). then you will just do

```
adjacencyMatirx.add(3 * 10000000 + 2);
```

Once you have processed all the inputs, then you can make the sparse adjacency matrix implementation above:

```
final int[] edgeArray = adjacencyMatrix.toIntArray(new int[adjacencyMatrix.size()]);
IntArrays.sort(edgeArray)
```

**Given an node, finding all adjacent nodes:**
So if you need all the nodes connected to node p, you would binary search for the next value that is greater than or equal to p * N (O(log (number of edges))). Then you will just traverse the array until you hit a value that is greater than or equal to (p + 1) * N. All the values you encounter will be nodes connected to p.

**Comparing it with the approach you mentioned in your question:**
It uses O(N*b) space complexity, where N (number of nodes) and b is the branching factor. It's lower bounded by the number of edges.

For the approach I mentioned, the space complexity is just O(E). In fact it's exactly e number of integers plus the header for the int array.

Answer (score 0):

I used `var graph = new Dictionary<long, List<long>>();`
See here for complete solution in c# - https://gist.github.com/newton3/a4a7b4e6249d708622c1bd5ea6e4a338

PS - 2 years but just in case someone stumbles into this.